# How do I make an android app to read specific <div>'s from a website needed a login aswell

Tags: java, android, html, xml

I need help creating an app that logs into a website and reads some data off the website so I can easily view it within the app.

[What I need to be read from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BGcS.png)

Comment: and what is a problem exactly? Which kind of help you want? You have to mention all the details.

Comment: so i am not sure as to how i can make a app from android that reads a website to show me an integer im not sure where i would start i have made apps before and worked with java, xml, js, c#, c, etc

Comment: start with finding some basic ANdroid tutorials, don't start from doing real project

Comment: I've done alot of projects ive just dont know how to read off a website I've used Databases with apps. I not new but I am new to reading off websites.

Comment: 1) download HTML page. 2) parse html page. Just add `android` keyword, and you have a ready-made google search query

Comment: Ahhh looking back at this is funny. I figured it out in a project a year later. I didn't know what web scraping was and the moment I learnt about it I found everything I wanted. Funny to know all my problems would've been solved if I was told "Google Web Scraping Idiot" hahaha. Thank you for your help though and sorry if anyone got this bumped.